# How to install an application like gimp from terminal and install all the available plugins showed in software center?

Tags: installation, command-line, gimp

What i want is to run from terminal `sudo apt-get install gimp` but also install all the available plugins!

So, i tried this `sudo apt-get install gimp*` BUT this installed all the packages with name gimpblablabla. So which is the right way to do this?

Thanks

edit---->[image]

So, from software center i am installing gimp and check all the boxes for what i want! The alternative to it from terminal is `sudo apt-get install gimp gimp-plugin-registry gimp-cbmplugs extremetuxracer-gimp-dev`?NO right?

Well, that question was not only for gimp but for other applications too!So, i want this for a deeper knowledge of installing from terminal! If i want to list for example the available plugins for gimp what is the way?

I hope it is not so confusing! Thanks very much for your answers!

Comment: Yes you would need to type all those names out. But this is a one time action (unless new plugins are created) since you can save it in a textfile and execute the install command from the textfile ;) TO ME it would have made a lot of sense if those creators of those packages would have started the name of their packages with `gimp-plugin`... or another common dominator... but alas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
apt-cache search gimp
```

to find all packages with gimp in the name or short description.  You can also then pipe that to grep and search for ones that also mention "plugin":

```
apt-cache search gimp | grep plugin
```

Comment: Well this is SOMETHING! You are very close for what i want, REALLY! Well is this command searching the plugins only within the repository , for example, of canonical?

Comment: Yep, only searching plugins which have an official package in the repositories that you have installed (just Canonical by default).

Answer (score 4):

You need to find out all the package names that you want to install and then you can put them behind `gimp` (with a space in between)

So ...

```
sudo apt-get install gimp gimp-data-extras gimp-flegita 
gimp-gmic gimp-gutenprint gimp-plugin-registry gimp-cbmplugs 
extremetuxracer-gimp-dev gvfs-backends xcftools
```

Oh and you can leave out gimp (it will install itself due to you installing gimp-plugin-registry).

Addition:

- gimp-flegita is a plugin to add scanners to gimp
- gimp-gmic is a pluging to manipulate GREYC's Magic Image Converter

Comment: Could you explain please the `gimp-flegita` or `gimp-gmic` etc?I want a generic way to install everything i want from terminal and with no GUI. Can i someway list the packages of an application?

Answer (score 0):

Gimp plug-ins and extensions ( **script-fu** ) is different by repositories. Each script-fu or extension written by different authors. So probably orient work to tasks is more right way ...
Common way is:
[**Install Script-Fus**](http://docs.gimp.org/2.6/en/install-script-fu.html)

```
cd home/username/.gimp-2.x/scripts
wget <URL to script filename.tar/.tar.bz2/.tar.gz etc>
sudo tar -xvfz <filename.tar/.tar.bz2/.tar.gz etc>
sudo rm -rf <filename.tar/.tar.bz2/.tar.gz etc>
```

You can check and get links and filenames here:
[**GIMP Plugin Registry Glossary**](http://registry.gimp.org/glossary)

Comment: HOW CAN I SEE THOSE SCRIPTS FROM TERMINAL SWIFT? I want to use only the terminal!thanks

Comment: it depends what you want to do